# Inductor real charcaterstics when connected to an ac supply

Tags: electric-current, capacitance, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

When we connect a dc source to an inductor we always use a resistor there so after solving that RL D.C. circuit we find an exponential function (e to the power R/L based)
But when we are considering A.C. supply applied on an RL circuit we usually first study about pure inductor circuit.
We use the solution of pure inductor circuit(that current must be lag behind the voltage Across inductor) and we just apply that result to the A.C. circuit..
But in my opinion that is wrong method.
If we consider with starting observing inductor with a RL circuit than we will definetly get an exponential function.
So why we are using result of pure  L circuit in RL circuit.
So where is the mistake in my view..[image]

Comment: Related question on EE.SE: [Response of a RC circuit and Frequency Response Theorem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/487534/6334)

Comment: @ThePhoton Unless I'm missing something, I don't think the link addresses the OP's question. If I understand it he wants to see the overall response to switching an as supply on to the series RL circuit. There will be an initial transient response followed by the steady state response. There should be equations for voltages and currents starting as soon as the switch is closed.

Answer (score 0):

In DC circuits the inductive element has no impedance, so the resistor is needed to maintain finite current. The time constant of the exponential growth curve, with both $R$ and $L$ present, is an important part of the theory.

In AC circuits the inductive element has a finite impedance which is frequency-dependent, so there is no need to complicate things while this is taught. The circuit impedance in the form of $X = R + jX_L$ comes after you have understood that bit. The DC case of $X_L=0$ is in fact the limit state as the frequency falls to zero.

Comment: I don't think this answer addresses the OP's question. If I understand it he wants to see the overall response to switching an ac supply on to the series RL circuit. There will be an initial transient response followed by the steady state response. There should be equations for voltages and currents as a  function of time showing both the initial transient conditions and final steady state conditions. It does complicate matters, but I think that's what he's after. But I could be wrong.

Comment: I does not satisfied with the answere but now i have known that where i can get my solution (probably at frequency response therorem)

Comment: ThanX for your comment